# Showing only basename of path in bash autocompletion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I notice that the autocompletion for the command 'cd' will only show the basename of a path, for example:

cd ../d/s[tab]
scripts secure

But when I build my own autocomplete function by editing COMPREPLY, it will always show the whole path as the results, like this:

my_func ../d/s[tab]
../d/scripts ../d/secure

Is there a way to make my autocomplete work as 'cd'?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ls -1` in your COMPREPLY if you need to show only the basename of the path.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much. But what does -1 means actually?

Comment: -1 means one per line, but we have a curious behavior in this case (which, unfortunately, I don't understand beyond "it works"). Notice that if you run ls, it lists your directory in a specific way, and running ls -1, it lists in a different way. BUT, if you redirect it into a file (as in ls > testA or ls -1 > testB) both files will be absolutely the same (you can even diff testA testB to make sure they're totally equal). So I suspect that ls -1 is not only changing the way it writes output on screen but also changing something related to pipes or redirects. I wish I knew better to explain.